# Raspberry Pi Zero and Waveshare 4 inch IPS screen

Tags: driver, touchscreen, pi-zero

I've tried to install this screen, used the image on the supplied CD, and the little light just flashes 8 times, so I go back to NOOBS, reinstall, then download the driver they supply from their site, install letter by letter their instructions and still all I get is a white IPS screen and nothing else. If I plug the HDMI back in it tries to boot and stops at
`Random: non blocking pool is initialised`

There is a kernel panic just above:
`Vfs: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (179,2)`

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Which light is flashing 8 times? The `ACT` light? According to [elinux.org](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) 8 flashes means `SDRAM not recognised. You need newer bootcode.bin/start.elf firmware.` I'm guessing their image is not made for the Pi Zero. (Sorry I'm not of much help; I'm currently facing a similar issue).

Comment: As far as I can see its the only led on the pi board, but thanks anyway, good to see I'm not the only one stuck

Comment: Oh forgot to say its a gpio connection

Comment: Ok, this gets weird, the supplied image with this screen boots and works with the pi2, but wont boot with the pi zero

Comment: Interesting. You might want to update the question with that. Since the Pi Zero just came out I'm guessing the image they made is in some way not compatible. Waveshare's [wiki page](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/4inch_RPi_LCD_(A)) for your LCD doesn't appear to have been edited since the Zero came out. They also have an alternative installation method (their `LCD-show*` packages). Make sure you get the right one (check the name, e.g. `LCD-show-151020.tar.gz for 2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie`) for your Raspbian version. Some of them change the kernel (to add drivers maybe?) while others don't.